# how to get my mac to use brew's installed python ?

Tags: python, homebrew

i think I have two versions of python on my system, what are the correct steps and/or what controls what version of python my system is using ? i can run python3 and get py3 to run, bu t what should my setup in general be ?

```
[jd@mbp ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
[jd@mbp ~]$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/python3/
./     ../    3.3.3/
[jd@mbp ~]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shall keep `python` pointing to a python 2.x install, whereas `python3` points to python 3.

Because there still are applications and/or libraries from your system relying on the fact that `python` is python2, and you may get things broken.

In case you can't run python3 from the command line, you should make sure you've got `/usr/local/bin` in `echo $PATH`, if you do not:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

and you can add that to your `~/.bashrc`.

If you still do not have `python3` callable from command line, you should run:

```
brew link python3
```

that will populate `/usr/local/bin` with python3 installation's scripts, but that step is being done automatically at `brew install python3` (just tested it right now).

Comment: so just consider my system good and use python3 as the command to run that version ?

Comment: indeed, that's about all :-)